# IDAPython: function parameters and return value

Tags: ida, idapython

I want to get a function's signature information: return type and parameters  from x64 binaries. I am able to achieve so, using

```
tif = idaapi.tinfo_t()
ida_nalt.get_tinfo(tif, ea)
function_type = tif.get_rettype()
metadata[function]["ret_type"] = function_type
funcdata = ida_typeinf.func_type_data_t()
for i,v in enumerate(funcdata):
        itype = ida_typeinf.print_tinfo('', 0, 0, idc.PRTYPE_1LINE, v.type, '', '')
        metadata[function]["parameter_list"].append(tuple([i, v.name,itype]))
```

This script works in a lot of cases, but fails in some simple cases, like for example

```
double retDouble()
{
  return 2.4;
}
```

In such case, I get an empty `tif` object, and thus I can't recover the return type — which is double in this case. I believe this happens in cases where there are no function parameters present (like in above case). In such case, How can I recover the return type (or at least recover the type, or is it not possible at all)? I want the type object and not the type as a string, the later can be achievable by parsing IDA disassembly and retrieving function signature by something like regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is available in the `rettype` field of the [`func_type_data_t` structure](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/structfunc__type__data__t.html).

Comment: thanks for your comment, but `function_details = idaapi.func_type_data_t();
    func_tinfo.get_func_details(function_details)` still gives me black output

Comment: @R4444 check that the type is actually a function type (`tif.is_func()`)

Comment: yes, I just checked. it gives me False for some functions and True for some

Comment: well, return type is only available for function types

Comment: yes, I am not sure I why I am getting the is_func as false though, because clearly the address belongs to the function, also if I use the decompiler, and I obtain tinfo by doing something like `decompiled.get_func_type(func_tinfo)` it gives me correct function type

Comment: Decomplier has its own type info which may be not present in the database. If you do Y, Enter in the function header in the decompiler then it will be stored in the database.

Comment: I see, thanks so much